# Find a coresponding software with BvSSHclient on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

I expect to install a software like BvSSHclient on Ubuntu, however, I still cannot find something like this after an hour searching on google. So can someone tell me what exactly I have to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are looking for an SSH client, you can check out [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) and see whether it meets your requirements.

You can also install it using the Terminal with the following command :

`apt-get install putty`

Use `sudo` if required.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a ssh client, you can install the metapackage `ssh` if it's not already installed.
To do this, open the software center and search for `ssh`, then install it.